# How to call suitelet at PageInit function of Client in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Please let me know how to call suitelet at PageInit function of Client in **NetSuite**.
I tried this in Page Init function of Client:

```
var var_url_servlet = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET','customscript_sl_addressvalidation','customdeploy_sl_addressvalidation', false);
```

I have inserted logs in `Suitelet`. But calling this method in `Client`. I can't see any logs.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just resolving the url, add another statement to make AJAX.

```
var var_url_servlet = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET','customscript_sl_addressvalidation','customdeploy_sl_addressvalidation', false);
//to send synchronous ajax, To make async add callback param
var response = nlapiRequestURL(var_url_servlet);
```

Also, for logging use browser's console APIs eg: console.log() instead of nlapiLogExecution(), and see the logs directly in browser's console for logs that are in context of client script

Comment: Thank you, works as a charm for me too, though I had to use true instead of false to get the absolute URL as the last parameter.